# Is there a way to put this PHP into an array and simplify it?

Tags: php, wordpress

The following code loads all .php files found in the specified folder (defined separately). Is there a way to put this into an array to simplify the code?

Only a couple of variables change but essentially the code repeats several times.

```
// The General Files

$the_general = opendir(FRAMEWORK_GENERAL);

while (($the_general_files = readdir($the_general)) !== false) {
    if(strpos($the_general_files,'.php')) {
        include_once(FRAMEWORK_GENERAL . $the_general_files);       
    }       
}

closedir($the_general);


// The Plugin Files

$the_plugins = opendir(FRAMEWORK_PLUGINS);

while (($the_plugins_files = readdir($the_plugins)) !== false) {
    if(strpos($the_plugins_files,'.php')) {
        include_once(FRAMEWORK_PLUGINS . $the_plugins_files);       
    }       
}

closedir($the_plugins);
```

There are several more sections which call different folders.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers,
James

Answer (score 5):

I nicer way to do this would to use [glob()](http://php.net/glob). And make it into a function.

```
function includeAllInDirectory($directory)
{
    if (!is_dir($directory)) {
        return false;
    }

    // Make sure to add a trailing slash
    $directory = rtrim($directory, '/\\') . '/';

    foreach (glob("{$directory}*.php") as $filename) {
        require_once($directory . $filename);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is fairly simple. See [arrays](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and [foreach](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

```
$dirs = array(FRAMEWORK_GENERAL, FRAMEWORK_PLUGINS, );

foreach ($dirs as $dir) {
    $d = opendir($dir);

    while (($file = readdir($d)) !== false) {
        if(strpos($file,'.php')) {
            include_once($dir . $file);       
        }       
    }

    closedir($d);
}
```

Comment: In theory you could have a file named 'something.php.jpg', so using `substr($file, -4)` would probably be better than `strpos(...)`.

Comment: Better to use `pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)` in that case.

Answer (score 1):

A better idea might be lazy loading via __autoload or spl_autoload_register, including all the .php files in a directory might seem like a good idea now, but not when your codebase gets bigger.

Your code should be layed out in an easy to understand heirarchy, rather than putting them all in one directory so they can be included easily. Also, if you dont need all of the code in the files in every request you are wasting resources.

Check http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php for an easy example.

Comment: I was going to suggest autoload, but the poster might be including code segments instead of classes.

Comment: All the files in the specified folders are WordPress functions which need to be loaded. They have actions to dictate the order in which they should be called.

Comment: @James: You're right, there are code segments instead of classes.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done pretty tightly:

```
$dirs = array(FRAMEWORK_GENERAL, FRAMEWORK_PLUGINS);
foreach($dirs as $dir) {
    if (!is_dir($dir)) { continue; }
    foreach (glob("$dir/*.php") as $filename) {
        include($filename);
    }
}
```

Put that in a function where $dirs comes in as a param and use freely.

Comment: Hit the nail on the head, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Many thanks.